# Can a UK Standard Visitor travel without the main applicant

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My mother is dependent on my father and her application is linked to my father's. After my parents have got their visa, will my mother be able to travel alone. I intend to have my mother in the UK for about 2-3 months and then my father would visit us for 2 weeks and both of them will return the their home country.

Can my mother travel to the UK by herself on a UK Standard visitor visa, if during her visa application she was shown as a dependent on my father?

Comment: What travel dates were stated in their visa applications? Was the plan to travel separately explained?

Comment: Yes, as dependent in this case means financially, and both of your parents would be issued their own individual visa. Their applications should state the separate plans, your mother for 2-3 months, your father for 2 weeks.

Comment: I am still in the process of applying for their visa, I have filled the forms and was wondering if they could travel separately. I will explain in their application of the separate travel plans. Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your mother can travel to UK on her own, as dependent in this case means financially, and both of your parents would be issued their own individual visa.

Each person files a separate UK visa application, although their applications can be linked when filing as a family so that only the primary would need to submit financial evidence. The [Supporting Documents Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) gives the details.

However, both applications should state their separate plans, that your mother would stay for 2-3 months, your father for 2 weeks at the end of that period, and that they plan to return home together.